# Ajax json POST and Spring MVC Controller

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have ajax json POST method like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "localhost:8080/webeditor/spring/json/", 
    data: JSON.stringify(contents),
    dataType: "json"
});
```

Controller to handle post request

```
JSONPObject json;
BindingResult result = new BeanPropertyBindingResult( json , "MyPresentation" );
@RequestMapping(value="json/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void savePresentationInJSON(Presentations presentation,BindingResult result) {
        //do some action

}
```

but I getting this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/webeditor/spring/json/. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

I'm not sure how to correct above error.

Comment: You are returning void, no need to use response body

Comment: it did not solve my problem, it no mapping found for HTTP

Comment: no I didn;t think it would, just an observation. But this all looks fine, there is no request mapping on the class ?

Comment: thanks for this=) yeap, 404 PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request

Comment: The method that this class is defined in, does that have a global request mapping - which is then prepended to the methods request mapping

Comment: look, I edit ajax. but now I request new error :XMLHttpRequest cannot load localhost:8080/webeditor/spring/json/. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

Answer (score 5):

My final work version

```
var jsonfile={json:JSON.stringify(contents)};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/webeditor/spring/json/", 
    data: jsonfile,
    dataType: "json"
});
```

AJAX, and

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/json/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void saveNewUsers( @RequestParam ("json") String json)
{
    System.out.println( json );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Passing JSON with Spring is fairly straight forward.  Consider the following jQuery function:

```
function processUrlData(data, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getCannedMessageAsJson.html",
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(responseData, textStatus) {
            processResponse(responseData, callback);
        },
        error : function(responseData) {
            consoleDebug("  in ajax, error: " + responseData.responseText); 
        }
    });
}
```

Now use the following String @Controller method...

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getCannedMessageAsJson.html", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public ResponseEntity<String> getCannedMessageAsJson(String network, String status, Model model) {

    int messageId = service.getIpoeCannedMessageId(network, status);
    String message = service.getIpoeCannedMessage(network, status);

    message = message.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
    message = message.replaceAll("\n", "");

    String json = "{\"messageId\": \"" + messageId 
    + "\", \"message\": \"" + message + "\"}"; 

    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    return new ResponseEntity<String>(json, responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

In my case the request is so simple that I'm just hardwiring the json formatting in the controller method, but you could just as easily use a library like Jackson to produce the json string.

Also as others have stated, verify that the "value" in the @RequestMapping is a unique, legitimate filename.  With the json method I show above you don't have to have a corresponding jsp page (in fact it won't use one).

Answer (score 0):

In the URL : url: "localhost:8080/webeditor/spring/json/"

webeditor must be war name or service name so in ur @RequestMapping(value="/webeditor/spring/json/" i think u should not have 'webeditor' it must be only **/spring/json**

normally 404 means the for the URL requst is wrong or no such service is running for that URL

Answer (score 0):

Your application should have a context root, which would precede the rest of your URL path. And you should also have a `servlet-mapping` defined in web.xml which defines which requests get directed to your Spring controllers. So if the context root of your application is "myapp" and your `servlet-mapping` is going to *.html, then your ajax call would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/myapp/webeditor/spring/json.html",
    data: JSON.stringify(contents),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        // Success Action
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like jQuery so why not try

```
$.getJSON('webeditor/spring/json', JSON.stringify(contents, function(data) {//do callbackstuff});
```

If you wanted to request cross domain the way to do it is like :-

```
cbFn = function(data) {
   // do callback stuff. 
}

    var ca = document.createElement('script');
                ca.type = 'text/javascript';
                ca.async = true;
                ca.src = server + '/webeditor/spring/json.jsonp?callback=cbFn';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(ca, s);
```

and also add the servlet mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>yourSevletName</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsonp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: "<url-pattern>*.jsonp</url-pattern>" is it "jsonp" or "json"?

Answer (score -1):

In yr jsp include the tag library like so

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
```

Then create a full url using spring

```
<c:url var="yourFullUrl" value="/webeditor/spring/json/" />
```

then create javascript variable based on this so you can use in Ajax

```
<script>
var yourUrl= '<c:out value="${yourFullUrl}"/>';
</script>
```

No use the javascriptvariable representing the url :

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: yourUrl, 
        data: JSON.stringify(contents),
        dataType: "json"
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can't generate a spring based url in js alone, you have to do what I said (or a close variation of). JS is client side, you need server side processing for spring url. O ryou coul dhardcode th ehost